# Android Input Method suggestion asynchronously from web service

Tags: android, asynchronous, web, methods, input

I wants to create a custome Input Method with word suggestions from a webservice in an asynchronous way. If it is not asysnchronouse , phone get stuck while connecting to internet. If I use Thread it cause an excpetion "ui can be touch only by the tread created ". I don't know runOnUIthread can be used or how. I understood that runOnUiThread activity method. Anybody please help. I used android Example app softkeybord.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand,
If the definition of the Thread is inside the Activity,
You can just call:

```
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (i++ < 1000) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            btn.setText("#" + i);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: it is not activity , it is Input method service
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

runOnUiThread not work because its not activity